# add typings for missing method (from a npm package)

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using the package `@types/cropperjs`
unfortunately it is behind the current cropper.js versions and lacks the method `scale`.
So far I just manually added the missing method to the d.ts file under node_modules (*this is obviously a bad idea, so don't do that! it was just a temp. fix*)

I tried to merge the definitions from `node_modules` with my own declaration.

```
declare class cropperjs {

  /**
   * Scale the image.
   *
   * @param scaleX The scaling factor to apply on the abscissa of the image.
   * When equal to 1 it does nothing. Default is 1
   * @param scaleY The scaling factor to apply on the ordinate of the image.
   * If not present, its default value is scaleX.
   */
   scale(scaleX: number, scaleY?: number): void;
}

export = cropperjs;
export as namespace Cropper;
```

the typings from the DefinitlyTyped Repo can be [found on github](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/12522ac23bbaab61df8d45eb92751a4dc478ab35/types/cropperjs/index.d.ts) (it looks similar but is too big to display here)

Here's how I import cropper in an angular component.

`import * as Cropper from 'cropperjs';`

Here's my tsconfig.json (parts of it)

```
 "typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types",
  "node_modules/@angular",
  "src/typings"
],
"types": [
  "jasmine",
  "node",
  "karma",
  "webpack",
   "cropperjs" 
]
```

I tried it with my custom typings folder an with the tripple slash reference notation.
But I can't figure out how I can successfully merge my and DefinitlyTyped's definitions so I can use cropperjs without having to fiddle around in node_module

P.S.
I already opened an issue with the updated definitions on github (no pull request, because at the time had almost no knowledge of git).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do that in typescript. Typescript has the concept of declaration merging, which is what allows us to extend types other people wrote, and you can merge interface and namespaces, but not classes. Look [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#disallowed-merges).

If the `@types/cropperjs` would have been written using interfaces, you could have extended that interface using your own declaration.

Here is an ugly hack you can do for now:

```
import * as Cropper from 'cropperjs';

interface MyCropper extends Cropper {
  scale(scaleX: number, scaleY?: number): void;
}

function CreateCropper(dom: HTMLImageElement, options: Cropper.CropperOptions): MyCropper {
  return new Cropper(dom, options) as MyCropper;
}
```

casting is always ugly, but at least you hide it in one place, I think it's reasonable...

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add another possible "solution". I say "solution" because it's in my opinion quite ugly but then again it's a workaround.

After seeing and reading (see Aviad Hadad's answer) that class merging is not possible and read about [typescripts node module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)
Basically if you import an non-relative path like `import * as Cropper from 'cropperjs` typescript will look for the appropriate files in a folder named `node_modules` and it starts in the directory in which the file with the import statement resides. It then traverses up (example taken from the typescript documentation)

- /root/src/node_modules/moduleB.ts
- /root/node_modules/moduleB.ts
- /node_modules/moduleB.ts (I assume that's the global node_modules directory)

Since typescript will also look for `d.ts` files I copied the whole `index.d.ts` from the `@types/cropperjs` package, renamed it to `cropperjs.d.ts` and put it in a folder named `/root/src/node_modules`. (and added the missing method)

if you trace the resolution with `tsc --traceResolution` you'll see that typescript will take the `d.ts` file from the custom `node_modules` directory.

The advantage with this solution is that you don't have to touch your code. As soon as `@types/cropperjs` has updated the missing method you can just delete your custom node_modules directory and everything will still work.
Disadvantage is you have to copy and paste code around.